# What would happen if a monochromatic light falls on an electron?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, visible-light, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics

An electron is not strictly free, but in terms of [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), we consider scattering events in an asymptotic framework where free particles would arise at $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$. So, I would like to know what happens to an electron, specifically it's momentum (or lack thereof) in these four scenarios taking [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) into consideration:

- If a monochromatic light falls on a free electron in presence of an external electromagnetic field.
- If a monochromatic light falls on a free electron as part of the asymptotic input of a scattering event.
- If a monochromatic light falls on a free electron as part of the asymptotic output of a scattering event.
- During the scattering event, an electron is no longer free, so what would happen if a monochromatic light falls on it **during** the scattering event.

I think that in the first scenario, it would very well mean the Coulomb field of a proton, and thus we would end up computing/calculating photo-electric effect in case of a hydrogen atom, however, I am pretty much interested in the answers to the last three scenarios. I apologize if the questions are ill-defined or if I am posting a duplicate question. Regards!